# Pandas grouping by week

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame in pandas like this:

```
Name  Date
A     9/1/21
B     10/20/21
C     9/8/21
D     9/20/21
K     9/29/21
K     9/15/21
M     10/1/21
C     9/12/21
D     9/9/21
C     9/9/21
R     9/20/21
```

I need to get the count of items by week.

```
weeks = [9/6/21, 9/13, 9/20/21, 9/27/21, 10/4/21]
```

Example: From 9/6 to 9/13, the output should be:

```
Name  Weekly count
A     0
B     0
C     3
D     1
M     0
K     0
R     0
```

Similarly, I need to find the count on these intervals: 9/13 to 9/20, 9/20 to 9/27, and 9/27 to 10/4.  Thank you!

Comment: I do not understand your week segmentation: 2021-09-13 was monday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be with the caveat of the definition of the first day of a week, you could take something in the following code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

#### I. Discontinuous index

Monday is chosen as the first day of week

```
#(1) Build a series of first_day_of_week, monday is chosen as the first day of week
weeks_index = df['Date'] - df['Date'].dt.weekday * np.timedelta64(1, 'D') 

#(2) Groupby and some tidying
df2 = ( df.groupby([df['Name'], weeks_index])
          .count()
          .rename(columns={'Date':'Count'})
        
          .swaplevel()   # weeks to first level
          .sort_index() 
          .unstack(1).fillna(0.0)
        
          .astype(int)
          .rename_axis('first_day_of_week')
      )

>>> print(df2)
Name                  A  B  C  D  K  M  R
first_day_of_week                        
2021-08-30            1  0  0  0  0  0  0
2021-09-06            0  0  3  1  0  0  0
2021-09-13            0  0  0  0  1  0  0
2021-09-20            0  0  0  1  0  0  1
2021-09-27            0  0  0  0  1  1  0
2021-10-18            0  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

#### II. Continuous index

This part does not differ much of the previous one.

We build a continuous version of the index to be use to reindex

Monday is chosen as the first day of week (obviouly for the two indices)

```
#(1a) Build a series of first_day_of_week, monday is chosen as the 
weeks_index = df['Date'] - df['Date'].dt.weekday * np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
#(1b) Build a continuous series of first_day_of_week
continuous_weeks_index = pd.date_range(start=weeks_index.min(), 
                                 end=weeks_index.max(),
                                 freq='W-MON')    # monday

#(2) Groupby, unstack, reindex, and some tidying
df2 = ( df
          # groupby and count
          .groupby([df['Name'], weeks_index])
          .count()
          .rename(columns={'Date':'Count'})
        
          # unstack on weeks 
          .swaplevel()    # weeks to first level
          .sort_index()
          .unstack(1)

          # reindex to insert weeks with no data
          .reindex(continuous_weeks_index)  # new index
        
          # clean up
          .fillna(0.0)               
          .astype(int)
          .rename_axis('first_day_of_week')
      )

>>>print(df2)
Name               A  B  C  D  K  M  R
first_day_of_week                     
2021-08-30         1  0  0  0  0  0  0
2021-09-06         0  0  3  1  0  0  0
2021-09-13         0  0  0  0  1  0  0
2021-09-20         0  0  0  1  0  0  1
2021-09-27         0  0  0  0  1  1  0
2021-10-04         0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2021-10-11         0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2021-10-18         0  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

#### Last step if needed

`df2.stack()`

Comment: Thank you.  Very helpful.

Comment: I have noticed that if the count is 0 for all names in a week, that row entry doesn't show in the final table.  Can we prevent that from happening?  For example, if we have all zeros for the week 9/13, I still want that row to show.

Comment: @Mark, I added a solution for a continuous index (weeks wise)

Comment: Thank you.  You're a pro!

Comment: Thank you very much.  One more question.  In the output above, if we don't have anything between the week of 8/30 and 9/6, then the entry for 8/30 doesn't show up.  I want to give my program a date range.  Example: If my start date is 9/1 and there is nothing for the week of 8/30, I still want to see zeros for 2021-08-30.  Same situation should apply to the ending date.  If my end date is 10/27 and there is nothing for the week of 10/25, I still want to see 0 entries for the week of 10/25.

Comment: Also, if I have data for only 1 week, I would still like to see 0 entries for all the prior and later weeks for my given date range.  Thanks!

Comment: Set the start and end dates in the line building continuous_weeks_index, and filter the out of range data if needed before processing.